# FLUTTER: The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown building: '[]' Dynamic call of null. Receiver: null Arguments: ["data"]

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to call HTTP API to show the information of products on the Pageview.builder but it gets the error The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown building: '[]' Dynamic call of null. Receiver: null Arguments: ["data"], I've tried many ways to solve it but it still get an error and can't display the data of HTTP API on app screen
Anyone can solve it, many thanks!

```
class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePage({super.key});

  @override
  State<HomePage> createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  List<Information> postList = [];
  int currentIndex = 0;
  late PageController _controller;
  @override
  void initState() {
    _controller = PageController(initialPage: 0);
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  var data;
  Future<void> getData() async {
    final response = await http
        .get(Uri.parse('https://berequirement.herokuapp.com/products'));

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      data = jsonDecode(response.body.toString());
    } else {}
  }
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(children: [
Expanded(
          child: Container(
            height: 500,
            width: 300,
            child: FutureBuilder(
                future: getData(),
                builder: (context, snapshot) {
                  if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
                    return const Center(child: Text('Loading ...'));
                  } else {
                    return PageView.builder(
                      controller: _controller,
                      itemCount: data.length,
                      onPageChanged: (int index) {
                        setState(() {
                          currentIndex = index;
                        });
                      },
                      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                        return Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(40),
                            child: Column(
                              children: [
                                Text(
                                  data[index]['data']['name'],
                                  style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                    fontSize: 22,
                                  ),
                                ),
                                const SizedBox(height: 20),
                                Text(
                                  data[index]['data']['code'],
                                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                  style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                      fontSize: 14,
                                      color: Colors.grey),
                                )
                              ],
                            ));
                      },
                    );
                  }
                }),
          ),
        ),
        Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: List.generate(
            postList.length,
            (index) => buildDot(index, context),
          ),
        ),



])}
```

Comment: could you add your api response too?

Comment: yes, i did it, could you give me a solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem might be located around here:

```
Text(
    data[index]['data']['name'],
    ...
 )
```

I've tried sending a GET request to your URL and the following was given:

```
{
    "success": true,
    "message": "Products found",
    "data": [
        {
            "name": "Shadow Witch",
            ...

        },
        {
            "name": "Sadness Mummy",
            ...

        },
        {
            "name": "Candy Witch",
            ...

        }
    ]
}
```

Given this, your `Text()` doesn't have the correct parameters. It should look like this:

```
    Text(
        data['data'][index]['name'],
        ...
    )
```

Also, this might be redundant, but in your `getData()` you don't need to call the `toString()` method on `response.body`:

```
...    
if (response.statusCode == 200) {
          data = jsonDecode(response.body);
        } else {}
...
```